# why some of my data wont appear in my table?

Tags: laravel

[image: This it the table that im wroking on as you can see i can pull the day its created but other data wont appear]

This is the html where i call the data as you can see only the date and id can be called and im confuse.

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Balance</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount Due</th>
      <th scope="col">Current Balance</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{$news->created_at}}</th>
      <td>{{$news->balance}}</td>
      <td>{{$news->id}}</td>
      <th>{{$news->current_balance}}</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>


</table>
```

[image: This is my database]

[image: this is the page view]
This is my function to show the data

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $borrows =  borrows::find($id);
        $news = borrows::find($id);
        
        // $borrows = DB::select('select * from borrows, payment_records 
   where id = $id');
        
       return view('borrows.show', compact('borrows' , 'news'));
    }
```

Comment: it should be error at where id = $id; try comment that also

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the  fields are as hidden in the model and therefore when converting to array they are removed.
Check in the borrows model if they are as hideen.

Comment: so i was mistaken $news = payment_record::find($id); i should have ise payment_record table but now it return this foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lending\resources\views\borrows\show.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

The `show` method inside the controller I assume, it's used to display one record as it takes the `$id` of the record `show($id)`.
In case you want to display all your borrows, you should do that in the `index` method inside your controller, the code will be like:

```
public function index()
    {
        $borrows = borrows::all();
        return view('borrows.all', compact('borrows'));
    }
```

And you should have a view named `all` to correspond to the `borrows.all` above.

Inside your `'all.blade.php'` you should loop over the `borrows` to display them on the table like:

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Date</th>
          <th scope="col">Balance</th>
          <th scope="col">Amount Due</th>
          <th scope="col">Current Balance</th>
    
        </tr>
      </thead>
     
      <tbody>
@foreach ($borrows as $borrow)
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{$borrow->created_at}}</th>
          <td>{{$borrow->balance}}</td>
          <td>{{$borrow->id}}</td>
          <th>{{$borrow->current_balance}}</th>
        </tr>
@endforeach
      </tbody>
     
    
    
    </table>
```

Comment: so i was mistaken $news = payment_record::find($id); i should have ise payment_record table but now it return this foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\lending\resources\views\borrows\show.blade.php)

Comment: The find($id); will return one record(one row of a table), you need to get all the rows with borrows::all(); to use foreach.